# AttributeError: 'FeatureChartParser' object has no attribute 'nbest_parse'

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk

I am trying to run this code, for natural language processing.

```
import  nltk
from nltk import load_parser
cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
query = 'What cities are located in China'
trees = cp.nbest_parse(query.split())
answer = trees[0].node['sem']
q = ' '.join(answer)
print(q)
```

But i am getting the following compilation error:

```
trees = cp.nbest_parse(query.split())
```

AttributeError: 'FeatureChartParser' object has no attribute 'nbest_parse'

I am using python3.4 and nltk 3.0a4 . What can I do now to run this?

Comment: May this question helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983494/python-and-nltk-how-to-analyze-sentence-grammar

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import  nltk
>>> from nltk import load_parser
>>> cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> trees = next(cp.parse(query.split()))
>>> answer = trees[0].label()
>>> answer
NP[SEM=(SELECT, City FROM city_table)]
```

Comment: This isn't exactly equivalent. First, you're only returning one tree. Second, you're only returning the first parsed tree, which likely isn't the "best" or most likely correct parsing.

Answer (score 1):

nbest_parse was deprecated in NLTK 3.0, to test example code, I have to use NLTK 2.0 instead.

Link: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0

Answer (score 0):

According to [nltk doc](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html)

```
>>> import  nltk
>>> from nltk import load_parser
>>> cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> for tree in cp.parse(query.split()):
    ....print(tree)
```