# Is something wrong with the way that I'm generating this NLTK grammar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I wrote this simple program with NLTK that's just supposed to print out the syntax tree. However, it prints nothing out even though the `RecursiveDescentParser` is being created. What's my problem? Am I defining the grammar incorrectly? Is something wrong with the way that I'm trying to iterate through the parser? Thank you in advance.

```
import nltk

'''The price of peace is rising.'''

grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S -> NP VP
  VP -> V NP | V NP PP
  PP -> P NP
  V -> "is" | "rising"
  NP -> Det N | Det N PP
  Det -> "the" | "of"
  N -> "price" | "peace"
  P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
  """)

sentence = "the price of peace is rising"
wordArray = sentence.split()

print(wordArray)

parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)

for tree in parser.parse(wordArray):
    print(tree)
```

Comment: You don't have a valid sentence `the price of peace is rising` - `Det N Det N V V` is not defined by the grammar, `the price with the peace is the price` is a valid sentence.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966067/nltk-chart-parser-is-not-printing/42966837#42966837

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, always start writing grammar in bite-size.

Let's start with an easy sentence `Peace is rising`.

We want the structure `S -> NP VP`, where:

- VP is an intransitive verb phrase, in this particular case, `is rising` comes with an auxiliary `is` and `rise` comes with the `-ing` progressive inflection.
- NP is simply a single noun.

[code]:

```
import nltk

your_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
VP -> AUX V 
V -> "rising"
AUX -> "is"
NP -> N
N -> "peace"
""")

parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(your_grammar)
sentence = "peace is rising".split()

for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
    print (list(tree))
```

[out]:

```
[Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['peace'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('AUX', ['is']), Tree('V', ['rising'])])]
```

Now to add the determiner to the NP with `NP -> DT NP | N`:

```
import nltk

your_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
VP -> AUX V 
V -> "rising"
AUX -> "is"
NP -> N | DT NP  
N -> "peace" | "price" 
DT -> "the"
""")

parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(your_grammar)
sentence = "the price is rising".split()

for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
    print (list(tree))
```

[out]:

```
[Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['price'])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('AUX', ['is']), Tree('V', ['rising'])])]
```

Finally, we can simply add the PP construction within the NP, with `NP -> NP PP` and `PP -> P NP`:

```
import nltk

your_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
VP -> AUX V 
V -> "rising"
AUX -> "is"
NP -> N | DT NP | NP PP  
N -> "peace" | "price" 
DT -> "the"
PP -> P NP
P -> "of"
""")

parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(your_grammar)
sentence = "the price of peace is rising".split()

for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
    print (list(tree))
```

which gives us the best possible parse in the top results.

[out]:

```
[Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['price'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('P', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['peace'])])])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('AUX', ['is']), Tree('V', ['rising'])])]
```

But it also comes with some nasty recursive loop errors, that looks something like this:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 158, in __getitem__
    return self[index[0]][index[1:]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 156, in __getitem__
    return self[index[0]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 150, in __getitem__
    if isinstance(index, (int, slice)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

It's because the `nltk.RecursiveDescentParser` tries to look for a parse recursively since `NP -> NP PP` and `PP -> P NP` rules can infinitely recur. If you would like to know why, try asking that as a separate question on StackOverflow ;P

One easy solution is to use `try-except`:

```
try:
    for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
        print (list(tree))
except RecursionError:
    exit()
```

But that's ugly! Instead, you could use a `ChartParser`:

```
import nltk

your_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
VP -> AUX V 
V -> "rising"
AUX -> "is"
NP -> N | DT NP | NP PP  
N -> "peace" | "price" 
DT -> "the"
PP -> P NP
P -> "of"
""")

parser = nltk.ChartParser(your_grammar)
sentence = "the price of peace is rising".split()

for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
    print (list(tree))
```

[out]:

```
[Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['price'])])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('P', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['peace'])])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('AUX', ['is']), Tree('V', ['rising'])])]
[Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['price'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('P', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('N', ['peace'])])])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('AUX', ['is']), Tree('V', ['rising'])])]
```